# Service call in a page constructor in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make a service call only once the page is loaded , but the page constructor doesn't support the async await pattern , so I have to make the same in OnAppearing with some checks so the service call is made only once.

What is best practise for the same i.e. if I want to make a service call only once.

Comment: Is `Lazy` an option?

Comment: You can store some `values` in settings and check in `OnAppearing` if the service has already been called. `OnAppearing` executes every time you navigate to a specific page. You can also call the service in `App.xaml.cs` in order to call it only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task to do the job.

See:

```
public MyClass()
{
    ... // Your stuff goes here
    Initialize();
}

private async void Initialize()
{
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        await ServerObjectReference.AsyncMethod();
    });
}
```

Comment: Method should be asynchronous to use the Task.

Comment: So weird... Whatever. See the edited answer @AshishKumar .

Comment: you have to add await Initialize() , then in turn it will have to made awaitable

Comment: No. As you said, you can't await in the constructor... did you tried it some ways I've suggested? (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Now I see... I use it a lot, but in my view model, not in page. I'm sorry.